# Create google chat space using api from postman

Tags: google-chat-api

```
\`Hi,
```

I am trying to create a space in google chat using api. So, for this I have configured OAuth2.0 and following details.Method: spaces.create" post methodHTTP Request: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.spaces.create"Authorization Scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.spaces.create"I could able to generate the access token but I am not sure about request body however I configured as follows:
*{
"name": "POC Test SPACE",
"spaceType": "DIRECT_MESSAGE",
"singleUserBotDm": "false",
"threaded": "false",
"displayName": ""
}

For this the response as follows:
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Method not found.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}

Actually our requirement is to send notifications on google chat using gmail id in place of sending emails.

Can anyone please suggest where/what I am missing or do I need to do in another way !!!

Regards,

Vamshi.

Answer (score 0):

per this article you have to be a member of the developer preview program to have access to this feature.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/05/Create%20Spaces%20and%20Add%20Members%20with%20the%20Google%20Chat%20API.html